# "Pull to Refresh" with appium using selenium webdriver with java for android

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium

How to script "Pull to Refresh" on android app screen with appium using selenium webdriver with java

Comment: which appium, java client you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a wrapper around inbuilt swipe function in selenium appium. Simulate a function similar to the user activity

```
public static void swipeDown(AppiumDriver driver) throws InterruptedException 
{
    Dimension  size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    System.out.println(size);

    //Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
    //Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
    //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.65);
    //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.
    int startx = size.width / 2;
    System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);

    //Swipe from Bottom to Top.
    driver.swipe(startx, endy, startx, starty, 1000);
    Thread.sleep(200);
```

}

Kindly change the swiping start and end point as per your need.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Swipe  is no more valid in latest version of the Appium (1.15 that I'm using.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, just create simple enum DIRECTION with values UP,DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT;

provide DOWN, and input how long your swipe be executed.

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction){
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            break;

        case UP:
            endY= (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY  = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);

            break;

    }

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(startX, startY)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
            .moveTo(endX, startY)
            .release()
            .perform();

}
```